# IIS7 Application Pool 4.5 framework

Tags: iis-7

I built a web app using dotNet 4.5. I went into IIS  and created a new app pool but there was not 4.5 option, only 4.0 and 2.0. I went to install 4.5 and it says "already installed". I do a google search and see infact the registry and explorer show it to be installed.
What gives?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5 version number is 4.0.30319. If it doesn't show up when creating a new App Pool in IIS you may need to re-register it using aspnet-regiis.exe from the framework dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the .NET Framework Version column shows "v2.0" and "v4.0" for .NET Framework versions, these equate to ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5.

Due to the internals of how application pools bind to .NET Framework versions, the actual version name written to configuration (and thus displayed in the tool) corresponds to the original .NET Framework file version.

Your question is tagged as IIS7 but the link information regarding .net versions is applicable.

Soruce: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

[image]